# Asymptotics of a sequence of exponentials

Tags: analysis, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

How can one show that 
\begin{equation}
\big|1 - e^{i(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n})}\big| = \frac{1}{n^2} + o\big(\frac{1}{n^2}\big)
\end{equation}
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

I tried using Taylor series, but there is a factor with an $i$, I then tried writing out the modulus but I can't seem to obtain this result.

Comment: "but there is a factor with an $i$": and ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I obtain something of this kind: \begin{equation} LHS = \big|\frac{i}{n(n+1)}+ \frac{1}{2n^2(n+1)^2}+ o(\frac{1}{n^2})\big| \end{equation} by using Taylor series on the exponential term. Then I tried writing out the modulus, but I can't seem to obtain an $\frac{1}{n^2}$ and get rid of the square root.

Comment: the real term is neglectible and can be ignored. Then the modulus of a sum is bounded by the sum of the moduli. Lastly, $1/n(n+1)\sim1/n^2$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust This doesn't yield an equality.

Comment: It does with a little effort, by absorbing the "undesirable" terms in the $o$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the derivative of $\exp$ at $0$ is $1$, so $\lim_{y \to 0} \frac {\exp(y)-1}{y} = 1$ .

Plug in $y_n = i(\frac 1{n+1} - \frac 1n) = \frac 1{in(n+1)}$ to get $\lim_{n \to \infty} in(n+1)(\exp(y_n)-1) = 1$.

Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac n{n+1} = 1$, you can multiply them to get $\lim_{n \to \infty} in^2(\exp(y_n)-1) = 1$.
Then taking modulus (which is continuous), you get $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^2|\exp(y_n)-1| = 1$.

Now you are done because this means $\lim_{n \to \infty}n^2(|\exp(y_n)-1|-\frac 1{n^2}) = 0$, so $|\exp(y_n)-1|-\frac 1{n^2} = o(\frac1 {n^2})$

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all we can write:

$$\left|1-\exp\left(\theta\cdot i\right)\right|=\sqrt{\left(1-\cos\left(\theta\right)\right)^2+\left(-\sin^2\left(\theta\right)\right)}=2\cdot\left|\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right|\tag1$$

When $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Then the idea is to use the Taylor series expansion of the sine?

Answer (score 0):

Let

$$\theta=\frac{1}{n+1} -\frac1n=-\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$

since

$$e^{i\theta}=1+i\theta+io(\theta)$$

$$\big|1 - e^{i\theta}\big|=\big|1 - 1-i\theta+io(\theta)\big|=|\theta| + o(|\theta|)$$

thus

$$\big|1 - e^{i(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n})}\big| =\frac{1}{n(n+1)}+o\left(\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\right)=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Comment: I haven't been accurate enough with my question. I have already tried using Taylor series on the exponential.

Comment: @b.g. I've update my solution by Taylor's series, the final result is a little bit differnt, I'm wondering where the mistake is.